# How do I display a pages on a sub folder view in Cakephp 2,4.x?

Tags: php, templates, cakephp

Is it possible to display the pages under a sub folder inside a view in cakephp?
Here's my folder structure:

```
<pre>
-Views
  |-Elements
  |-Emails
  |-Errors
  |-Helpers
  |-Homes
  |-Layouts
  |-Messages
  |-Pages
  |-Resources
  |-Scaffolds
   |-Tutors
    |-ManageStudents
     |-addlectures.ctp
     |-editlecture.ctp
     |-deletelecture.ctp
  |-managestudents.ctp
  |-index.ctp
  |-profile.ctp
 |-Webroots
 </pre>
```

Now how do I display the ctp files under tutors/managestudents?
I tried typing in the browser localhost/school/tutors/managestudents/addlectures but that doesn't work.

i did also tried using the html helper link but still no luck

```
      $this -> html -> link ('Add lectures, array('controller' => 'tutors, 'action' =>    'ManageStudents/addlectures');
```

from what I have observed cake only displays the files under the view but It can't access the files inside a sub folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in the `TutorsController.php`, you have to render it like the ff:

```
  ...
  public function addlectures() {
    ...
    $this->render('ManageStudents/addlectures');
  }
  ....
```

And then, you have to configure `routes.php` which is found in app/Config like this:

```
...
Router::connect('/Tutors/ManageStudents/addlectures', array('controller' => 'tutors, 'action'=> 'addlectures'));
..
```

this way you can add link like this:

```
$this->Html->link ('Add lectures, array('controller'=>'tutors, 'action' =>'addlectures');
```

and the browser will output it like `..../Tutors/ManageStudents/addlectures`

> Note: The whole Tutors folder should be inside app/Views folder

Hope it Helps!